# How to paint a selected cells in a drawgrid using a button click

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

How do I paint inside a Delphi drawgrid cells after selecting the cells using mouse and by clicking on a button. Cells to be painted after pressing the button.

Comment: CAn you show any code that you have so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store drawing information in a separate container, such as an array with the same number of items as their are cells in the grid, then use the grid's `OnDrawCell` event to paint the cells as needed using the information currently stored in the container.  To update the drawing, simpy update the contents of the container as needed and then `Invalidate()` the grid to trigger a repaint so the `OnDrawCell` event uses the new information.

**Update:** For example:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls, Vcl.Grids;

type
  CellInfo = record
    BkColor: TColor;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    DrawGrid1: TDrawGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
      Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Cells: array of CellInfo;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

uses
  Vcl.ExtCtrls;

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TGridRect;
  Row, Col: Integer;
begin
  R := DrawGrid1.Selection;
  for Row := R.Top to r.Bottom do
  begin
    for Col := R.Left to R.Right do
    begin
      Cells[(Row * DrawGrid1.ColCount) + Col].BkColor := clBlue;
    end;
  end;
  DrawGrid1.Invalidate;
end;

procedure TForm1.DrawGrid1DrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  CellIndex: Integer;
begin
  CellIndex := (ARow * DrawGrid1.ColCount) + ACol;

  if gdFixed in State then
  begin
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := DrawGrid1.FixedColor;
  end
  else if (State * [gdSelected, gdHotTrack]) <> [] then
  begin
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
  end else
  begin
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.Brush.Color := Cells[CellIndex].BkColor;
  end;

  DrawGrid1.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);

  if gdFixed in State then
    Frame3D(DrawGrid1.Canvas, Rect, clHighlight, clBtnShadow, 1);

  if gdFocused in State then
    DrawGrid1.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(Cells, DrawGrid1.RowCount * DrawGrid1.ColCount);
  for I := Low(Cells) to High(Cells) do
  begin
    Cells[I].BkColor := DrawGrid1.Color;
  end;
end;

end.
```

Comment: you were 1st to post the answer :-)  Well, this container should better be made as indexed property of the form. Thus changing the value of the flag would auto-call the Invalidate from setter

Comment: if I need to hide the grid lines in between selected cells. how to do that.

Comment: @furathamaKos: You would have to turn off grid lines for the entire grid, by setting the `GridLineWidth` property to 0, or removing the `goVertLine` and `goHorzLine` frags from the `Options` property.

Comment: Is it possoble to change grid line color same as painted color of the cell

Comment: The coloring of native grid lines is fixed, it cannot be customized. If you want custom grid line colors, you will have to disable the native grid lines and then draw your own grid lines as part of your `OnDrawCell` code.

Comment: I am trying to write a booking system. now what happens is when I paint the grid with click of button the cells get painted correctly. but when I press any arrow key the cells get painted in multiple locations. here is the link http://rapidshare.com/files/2323994902/grid_multiple.jpg

Comment: please have a look at this ---- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251794/delphi-drawgrid-shows-multiple-instance-of-painted-cells-when-any-arrow-key-is

Comment: is it possible to modify the above code to draw the column grid lines in every other column.