# Delphi -drawgrid shows multiple instance of painted cells when any arrow key is pressed. how to correct it

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, pascal

when I press the button selected cells get painted in Delphi drawgrid. but when I press any arrow key the painted cells appear multiple times.

[image]

the picture shows 3 blocks. the blue one is the actual and the 2 aqua ones are the ones painted after pressing any arrow key

the current (or some date)  date is passed when calling the create_env procedure.

```
    unit bookings2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ExtCtrls, Vcl.Grids, Vcl.StdCtrls,
  Data.DB, Data.Win.ADODB;

type
  CellInfo = record
    BkColor: TColor;
  end;
  TScheduleItem = record
    Text : string;
    Row : integer;
    FirstX : integer;
    LastX : integer;
    Res_ID, Room_No :string;
  end;

  TArr_Rows = record
    row_no: integer;
    room_no: string;
  end;

  TArr_Col = record
    col_no: integer;
    b_date: Tdate;
  end;

  Tbookings2_frm = class(TForm)
    Panel1: TPanel;
    Panel2: TPanel;
    bGrid: TDrawGrid;
    Button1: TButton;
    qRooms: TADOQuery;
    qRoomsRoom_No: TStringField;
    qRoomsRoomType: TStringField;
    qRoomsDescription: TStringField;
    qRoomsdefault_price: TBCDField;
    qRoomsmax_pax: TIntegerField;
    qRoomsroom_status: TStringField;
    procedure bGridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
      Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
    procedure create_env(start_date:tDate);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    Cells: array of CellInfo;

  public
    { Public declarations }
    tot_rooms:integer;
    rooms:array of string;
    Shedule_item:array of TScheduleItem;
    Arr_Rows:array of TArr_Rows;
    col_count:integer;
    days_h, sun_mon, mon:array[0..50] of string;
    short_days:array[1..7] of string;
    ShortMonthNames : array[1..12] of string;
  end;

var
  bookings2_frm: Tbookings2_frm;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

uses data, data_guest;

procedure Tbookings2_frm.bGridDrawCell(Sender: TObject; ACol, ARow: Integer;
  Rect: TRect; State: TGridDrawState);
var
  CellIndex: Integer;

begin
  CellIndex := (ARow * bGrid.RowCount) + ACol;

  if gdFixed in State then
  begin
    bGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := bGrid.FixedColor;
  end
  else if (State * [gdSelected, gdHotTrack]) <> [] then
  begin
    bGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := clHighlight;
  end else
  begin
    bGrid.Canvas.Brush.Color := Cells[CellIndex].BkColor;
  end;

  bGrid.Canvas.FillRect(Rect);



  if gdFocused in State then
    bGrid.Canvas.DrawFocusRect(Rect);

end;

procedure Tbookings2_frm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TGridRect;
  Row, Col: Integer;
begin
  {
  R.Left :=6;
  R.Top:=3;
  R.Right:=8;
  R.Bottom:=3;
}

  R := bgrid.Selection;
  //bGrid.Selection:=R;
  for Row := R.Top to r.Bottom do
  begin
    for Col := R.Left to R.Right do
    begin
      Cells[(Row * bGrid.RowCount) + Col].BkColor := clAqua;
    end;
  end;


end;

procedure Tbookings2_frm.create_env (start_date:tDate);
var
  room_count, row_count:integer;
  I, ACol, FixedWidth: integer;
  stDate, endDate:tDate;
  year,month,day,s_day:word;
  s, str1, str_stDate, str_endDate:string;
begin

    //check how many rooms
    qRooms.Close;
    qRooms.SQL.Clear;
    qRooms.SQL.Add('select * from pm_Rooms where room_status = ''AVAIL'' ');
    qRooms.Open;


    tot_rooms:=qrooms.RecordCount;
    SetLength(rooms, tot_rooms+4);

    SetLength (Shedule_item, 50);
    SetLength (Arr_Rows , tot_rooms+3);


    stDate:=start_date-10;
    endDate:=stDate+50;

    room_count:=qrooms.RecordCount;
    bgrid.RowCount:=room_count+3;    // 3 fixed rows

    with bgrid do
       begin
         for I := 1 to ColCount - 1 do
          begin
             bgrid.ColWidths[i]:=30;
             //bgrid.Canvas.
          end;

       end;
    bgrid.ColWidths[0]:=100;


//-------------------------
    SetLength(Cells, bGrid.RowCount * bGrid.ColCount);
    for I := Low(Cells) to High(Cells) do
    begin
      Cells[I].BkColor := bGrid.Color;
    end;
end;

end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your cell array index calculation `(Row * bGrid.RowCount) + Col` is incorrect. It should be `(Row * bGrid.ColCount) + Col` since there are ColCount elements per row.

Comment: when i change the code in the button click even as Cells[(Row * bGrid.ColCount) + Col].BkColor := clAqua; its not working

Comment: Did you change the calculation in both the places it occurs? Are the symptoms different or the same? I know the cell index calculation is wrong. There may be other things wrong as well.

Comment: are you reffereng to     SetLength(Cells, bGrid.RowCount * bGrid.ColCount);
    for I := Low(Cells) to High(Cells) do
    begin
      Cells[I].BkColor := bGrid.Color;
    end;

Comment: I am referencing `Cells[(Row * bGrid.RowCount) + Col].BkColor := clAqua;` and `CellIndex := (ARow * bGrid.RowCount) + ACol;`. The reference to `RowCount` should be `ColCount` in both cases.

Comment: Your `SetLength(Cells, bGrid.RowCount * bGrid.ColCount);` is ok, btw.